# Windows Service application with a GUI frontend

Tags: .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I am attempting to program a Windows Service with VB.net 2010 that additionally included a Windows Form, so that the admin can load the Windows Form GUI after installing the service (so that they can change some of the Properties that are stored in the My.Settings.  `<config file>` from the core project.

I would like to have a separate .exe executable file once I build the project (so the person running it can either install the service using installutil.exe or run the GUI application)
- But they have to be in the same project because I need the GUI to access the stored properties from the My.Settings.Properties stored in the *application*.exe.config

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You need to write the library that is part of the service and executable. Minimum 3 assemblies. One win service. Another - win app. Third - api, which used by service and app

Comment: Hi @John Saunders: How did you solve this eventually?

Comment: @ilanS: solve _what_? I just edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your GUI application.
2. Then add the service classes to it.

Now you can install the service via InstallUtil.

Or you can run the .exe directly from Explorer or Cmd.exe and the GUI will open.

Both the service and the GUI will read from the same config file because they are the same assembly.

*Of course, this is just one method.  @T.S. offered another method that would work equally well if implemented properly.*

A quick rundown on how to do this:
1. Create the WinForms app
2. Add references for System.Configuration.Install and System.ServiceProcess
3. Create your service class which inherits from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase and overrides the appropriate methods.
4. Create your Installer which inherits from System.Configuration.Install.Installer
5. Mark your installer class with the RunInstaller(True) attribute
6. Make the installer .ctor look something like this:

```
    Public Sub New()
        Dim spi As ServiceProcessInstaller = New ServiceProcessInstaller
    Dim si As ServiceInstaller = new ServiceInstaller

    spi.Account = ServiceAccount.LocalSystem

        si.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual
        si.ServiceName = "Service1"

        Installers.Add(si)
        Installers.Add(spi)

    End Sub
```

Comment: That sounds like a good plan, do you have any examples of how this is done?  Thank you for the advice, I appreciate it.

Comment: there you go.  anything more and you will need to find yourself a good tutorial site or book or some-such